# Ignore a specific reference for garbage collection

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Let's say I have this:

```
public static class FooKeeper
{
    public static List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
}


public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        FooKeeper.foos.Add(this);
    }
}
```

I would like to do so that when an object of type Foo gets garbage collected, then I would manually remove it from the list in the FooKeeper class. Of course that doesn't make sense, since Foo objects cannot be garbage collected because FooKeeper will always have a reference to them.

Is there any way to tell GC to ignore that reference that the list in FooKeeper has? or some other way around this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to interfere with the garbage collection cycle - your classes don't seem to have anything that warrant that. As long as an instance is referenced, the GC will leave it alone. If it's not referenced, you normally don't have to do anything - the GC will pick it up when it runs.

Comment: I am trying to do a timer class for Unity3d, I could show you the full code if you want, but you would need to know how unity works, and I don't think it would be relevant.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. You have a pulic static list of objects - it doesn't matter what objects these are because they're owned by the list. If the list is not the owner of these objects, maybe you should re-think how you store them. Based on your question and comments, this sounds like an X/Y problem to me - this is why I asked what is the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [WeakReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712738(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve what you want.

```
public static List<WeakReference<Foo>> foos = new List<WeakReference<Foo>>();
```

Comment: I think I cannot do that. If I type "WeakReference<Foo> test;" the compiler says "The non-generic type cannot be used with type arguments"; When adding to the list I have tried this though: FooKeeper.foos.Add(new WeakReference(this).Target as Foo); , but the object doesn't get collected.

Comment: You should update your .Net framework up to 4.5 version.

Comment: Oh so that's the issue. I'm working with Unity and it doesn't have support for .Net 4.5 =/

Comment: @FelipeMüller There should be a non-generic WeakReference class, too that you can derive from. It's pretty easy to do so, although I'm not sure it's the right solution to your problem.